# How to get the value of html attributes to use it in flask with mysql_db

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I am trying to make a ecommerce site using flask and raw mysql i.e. using flask_mysqldb to write my own mysql query. I am trying to use dynamic routing to display data in a single template based on their id to avoid creating multiple templates for different products. But i am stuck as i cannot get the id of the products to pass it as a parameter in the mysql query. How to get the html tags attribute values to pass to the sql query as a parameter??
My route:

```
@app.route('/products/')
def product_details():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    productID = request.args.get('id')
    print(productID)
    
    cursor.execute('SELECT productCode, productName FROM Products WHERE productCode = %s', (productID, )
    )
    products = cursor.fetchone()
    return render_template('product-details.html', products=products)
```

My html files

products.html:

```
<div>
{% for product in products %}
    <h1><a href={{url_for('product_details', pk=product.productCode) }} id={{product.productCode}}>{{product.productName}}</a></h1>
    <p>Rs. {{product.price}}</p>
    {{product.productCode}}
{% endfor %}
```

product-details.html:

```
<h1 id={{products.productCode}}>{{products.productName}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a mismatch between the query parameters you are sending to, and expecting in `product_details`.

You are sending `pk` in your `url_for` call but are looking for `id` in `productID = request.args.get('id')`.

The solution is to look for `pk` in `product_details`: `productID = request.args.get('pk')`.

Note that anything information outside the `url_for` call is not visible to Flask i.e. Flask does not have access to the `<a>` tag's `id` attribute.